# C++ proto2 nested message has field checks

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

In C++ proto2 is it required to do a `has_` check before trying to access nested proto message fields?

```
message Foo {
  optional Bar1 bar_one = 1;
}

message Bar1 {
  optional Bar2 bar_two = 2;
}

message Bar2 {
  optional int value = 3;
}
```

```
Foo foo;
if (!foo.has_bar_one() || !foo.bar_one().has_bar_two() || !foo.bar_one().bar_two().has_value()) {
  // No value
}
```

or is it fine to just do:

```
if (!foo.bar_one().bar_two().has_value()) {
  // No value
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking the generated code, it seems your second approach will do just fine. The generated code for `bar_one` is:

```cpp
inline const ::Bar1& Foo::_internal_bar_one() const {
  const ::Bar1* p = bar_one_;
  return p != nullptr ? *p : reinterpret_cast<const ::Bar1&>(
      ::_Bar1_default_instance_);
}
inline const ::Bar1& Foo::bar_one() const {
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(field_get:Foo.bar_one)
  return _internal_bar_one();
}
```

and basically what this is doing is that, it will provide the object if it is set, and it will provide a default instance if its not. This will do the same for `bar_two` and for `value`.

So in the end if you check `has_value`, and its true, it means all the above objects are set, and if its false, at least `value` is not set. So if you just care about `value`, your second check will do just fine.

Comment: And by extension, if one were to want to set value, that's when you'd have to check out the nested objects to see if there's a real bar_two into which the value can be added.